AJAX: get old data with correct server response
I make simple quiz and learn AJAX requests.
I have such key HTML elements for this example:
<div id = "content">
<button id = "answer1" onclick="checker1()"><?php echo $myrow["answer1"]; ?></button>
<button id="Change-text-button" onclick="nextQuestion();">Change text</button>

</div">

For checking quiz result I have JS script
<script>
function checker1() {
    var userSolution = document.getElementById('answer1').innerText;    
    var correct_answer = '<?php echo $right_answer?>';  
    if (userSolution === correct_answer)
    {
    document.getElementById("answer1").style.background = 'green';}
      else {
     document.getElementById("answer1").style.background = 'red';}
</script>

As a result I change Button's text and check this text with correct answer with Javascript function nextQuestion() by AJAX (without JQuery) using standart code.
<script>
function  nextQuestion(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
          }
        }
     
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://sameword.ru/game/game_basis.php');     
    xhr.send();
}
</script>

As a result I get html correct code (xhr.responseText) and trying to relad div block (id ="content").
Problem with checker1() function with variable "correct_answer".
I see that server sends correct html text to browser. HTML from server response:
<script>
  function checker1() {
    var userSolution = document.getElementById('answer1').innerText;    
    var correct_answer = 'some correct answer'; // answer is updated correctly
    if (userSolution === correct_answer)
    {
    document.getElementById("answer1").style.background = 'green';}
      else 
     {
     document.getElementById("answer1").style.background = 'red';}
</script>

It's OK with variable "userSolution". But when I alert variable "correct_answer" (alert(correct_answer);) I get answer that server send when I started my 'https://sameword.ru/game/game_basis.php' page first time (or after refreshing page).
As I anderstand I sent request to server 'https://sameword.ru/game/game_basis.php'. Then browser got html to read as xhr.responseText.
I found that xhr.responseText is just text and script tags and Javascript can't get to them.
But why I see this  tags in browser F12 regime in propper way and how to make this all JS scripts (I;ve got few of them) to work after getting them in xhr.responseText?

Off topic (but might help) - consider using fetch() instead of xhr: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

This line document.getElementById("option1").innerText   =  "<?php echo $myrow['option1'];  ?>"; will be rendered when the page is first generated - so will not change on each ajax call/response.   Look at the rendered HTML in your browser - it will be .innerText = "fixed vaue";.  You need to read the value from the ajax response and use that.

You have misunderstood how the technologies you're using work. I would recommend you to read What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?. While reading it, remember that your PHP code is server side and your JavaScript/HTML/CSS are client side.

Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?

@fdomn-m Yes, I have this correct updated value but I can`t understand how to get it. I can get standart xhr.responseText but then do I need to parse it?

Also, depending on number of results, you can get the same result twice. You may want to keep already seen in a session

@brombeer  I know about this and it's not a problem for my old php version.

An old PHP version, yes. PHP5.6 ended security support about 5 years ago
